# 2014 FCC Closed Captioning Requirements

Tags: android, android-video-player

New FCC requirements that become effective January 1st 2014 require certain video content to have customizable close captioning (font, font size, text color, opacity, etc). See article:

http://www.insidetechmedia.com/2012/08/22/fcc-extends-online-closed-captioning-user-control-mandate-until-january-2014/

Anyone have any idea whether such support is in the works for the built in android video player in the coming Android releases? And thirdparty libraries with such support? Thanks!

Comment: For those who didn't read through the link, this only applies to "online content that has previously aired on television".

Comment: @Geobits - the question isn't about meeting the requirement, but about making use of the data that this requires be embedded (even if only in some content, though there's always the chance utilization might become broader than the actual requirement)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh, I get that. I didn't want anyone to freak out and think that every `VideoView` they created needed to have customizable captions, so I was just clarifying what the OP meant by "certain video content".

Comment: Ah, sorry to anyone that freaked out when reading this!

Answer (score 2):

We've encountered the same requirement at Flixster, as our app provides full-length streaming service. KitKat 4.4 added some support for closed captioning, but it's limited to WebVTT captioning format and KitKat devices.

We had to develop a solution that tailored to our needs, which included the abilities to parse SMPTE-TT/TTML captioning format, customize captioning preferences for pre-KitKat devices, and render advanced closed captioning on top of a VideoView.

This has been integrated into our app, and we've made this captioning library open source, so check it out and see if it can help your app in any way!
https://github.com/flixster/flixster-android-closedcaptions

Comment: Thanks for providing this @yuntao, really appreciate it. I'll check it out and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if you read the article, "Only online-delivered full-length programming that previously appeared on television with captions in the United States is covered by the new rules".

Second, [text tracks have been supported in Android since Android 4.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Multimedia), though it suffers from limited documentation and [apparently some bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=47933).

Third, as with pretty much everything in Android, you will find out what "is in the works" when we do, which will be when updates are released. Google does not usually say much in advance about a release, except maybe what "tasty treat" is the code name.

Comment: Yep, did note the full-length online content part, and the app I'm working on is covered under that. I was hoping that there's a thirdparty library that may have some/all of this supported so as not to have to do this myself. I will look into text tracks and in the mean time, if anyone has any more details on a thirdparty library it'd be appreciated!